# Read different class than the collection actual class from mongodb

Tags: java, class, mongodb, collections

I'm using MongoDB, latest version, in Java & Spring.

I want to be able to fill a class of type NotA from a collection which stores class type A.

Class A and Class NotA are exactly the same, with one difference: class NotA's name is, well, not A :)

for the sake of argument, class A looks like so:

```
public class A {
    String name;
    String domain;
}
```

And the A collection has objects which look like so:

```
{ "_id" : "b7990a90-7d95-4879-bb4a-5ec2fd13e262", "_class" : "com.someservice.A", "name" : "Dan", "domain":"global"}
```

For reasons unrelated to this question I can't read into A and then copy to NotA, I have to read directly to NotA (or some other object which is *NOT* A in between, and then to NotA, if there's no other choice).

I suppose I can read a DBObject and then manually copy all the fields, but would rather let the default reflection mechanism do its thing.

I've set the @Document annotation of NotA to @Document(collection = "A") but that's not enough, I need the rest of the way.

I'm guessing there's a simple solution to this problem, I just can't figure it out.  Help?

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible on your side - you can update your documents directly in Mongo collection to adjust `_class` value:

```
{ "_id" : "b7990a90-7d95-4879-bb4a-5ec2fd13e262", "_class" : "com.someservice.NotA", "name" : "Dan", "domain":"global"}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible since I don't want to directly alter data.